# How to clip just one column of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe comprised of 3 columns: from [datetime64], to [datetime64], value [float64].
I just want to clip the "value" column to a maxmimum value.

`df = dfo.clip(upper=100)`

fails with `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'`

How can I clip just on column of a dataframe?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify column:

```
dfo['value'] = dfo['value'].clip(upper=100)
```

If possible multiple columns:

```
cols = ['value', 'another col']
dfo[cols] = dfo[cols].clip(upper=100)
```

Or if need clip all numeric columns filter them by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
dfo[cols] = dfo[cols].clip(upper=100)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `inplace=True` to avoid the assignment:

```
dfo['value'].clip(upper=100, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers modify the original dataframe which is not what OP's example did.

The correct answer would be:

```
df = dfo.copy()
df["value"].clip(upper=100, inplace=True)
```

This cannot be done in one line unfortunately.